# Select query from more tables, which have the same structure

Tags: php, mysql, union

How I can select queries from more tables, when columns has the some struture. so I want to select id, poza, etc. from travel and istorie tables using a variable

```
    $sql = "SELECT id, titlu, link, poza, alt, keywords FROM istorie WHERE approved='1' LIKE '%''".$keyword."''%'='%''".$keyword."''%' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3" ;
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if(!$query){
     printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
    exit();}
$istorielist = '';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $id = $row["id"];
    $titlu = $row["titlu"];
    $link = $row["link"];
    $poza = $row["poza"];
    $alt = $row["alt"];
    $istorielist .= '<div id="articol-content-more"><a href="/istorie/'.$link.'"><img src="/images/'.$poza.'.jpg"class="articol-content-more-image" alt="'.$alt.'"><p class="articol-content-more-title">'.$titlu.'</p></a><span><a class="articol-content-more-afla" href="/istorie/'.$link.'">Citește mai multe</a></span><span class="articol-content-more-fl"><div class="fb-share-button" data-layout="button_count" data-href="http://esticurios.ro/istorie/'.$link.'"></div></span></div>';
}
mysqli_free_result($query);
```

I want to integrate also the query from the **table travel** , not only from the table **istorie** , both have the some structure **id, titlu, link, poza, alt, keywords**

Comment: use union all in your query. select id from t1 union all select id from t2

Comment: can you give me a e.g. of the php code? i don t know

Comment: here you have some examples https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/union_all.php

Answer (score 0):

If the number and the type of the column match between the two table you can use union or union all
Union select only the dictinct rowse between the two table, Union ALL select all the rows

```
$sql = "SELECT id, titlu, link, poza, alt, keywords 
          FROM istorie 
          WHERE approved='1' LIKE '%''".$keyword."''%'='%''".$keyword."''%' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3
          UNION ALL 
        SELECT id, titlu, link, poza, alt, keywords 
          FROM travel  
          WHERE approved='1' LIKE '%''".$keyword."''%'='%''".$keyword."''%' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3              
          " ;
```